# JS: Replace quotes between an specific symbol

Tags: javascript, json, regex

Let's say I have the string:

```
"Audio":[{"ID":"0","Codec": "AC-3","Info":"192 Kbps, 48.0 KHz (2 channels)","Language":"Spanish (##He aqui "el teléfono que nunca suena" pero debería##)","Default":"Yes"}]
```

And I want to convert into:

```
"Audio":[{"ID":"0","Codec": "AC-3","Info":"192 Kbps, 48.0 KHz (2 channels)","Language":"Spanish (He aqui \"el teléfono que nunca suena\" pero debería)","Default":"Yes"}]
```

As you can see, I want to escape all the quotes that exists between the "##" symbols, addtionally remove that symbols too, how can I achieve this by using the `replace()` method? I mean how could be the regex pattern. Thanks

Comment: How did you end up with the invalid JSON in the first place? It would probably be easier to fix it there, instead of papering over the problem afterwards.

Comment: I second that. Never create JSON "manually". Always use a data structure and a JSON serialization function and you won't ever have this kind of problem. JSON serialization is available for every every half-way modern programming language. There is no excuse for not using it.

Comment: Is from a template for MediaInfo. There's no way to apply some sort of format, is just simple text, so the only solution for unexpected quotes that I found is to delimit fields with "##", so can anyone have an actual response?

Answer (score 1):

If you're intent on doing this, then

```
input.replace(/##(.*?)##/g, function(match) { return match.replace(/"/g, '\\"'); })
```

should do the job.

This replaces all the `##...##` sequences with the result of replacing quotes inside them with the escaped quote.

Comment: It should be `/##(.*?)##/g`

Comment: It works, now if I just take out also the ## part...but how

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = '"Audio":[{"ID":"0","Codec": "AC-3","Info":"192 Kbps, 48.0 KHz (2 channels)","L##a"g##uage":"Spanish (##He aqui "el teléfono que nunca suena" pero debería##)","Default":"Yes"}]';
var result = str.replace(/##(.*?)##/g, function(v) { return v.replace(/"/g, "\\\""); });

print(result)
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/3Ntjzd)**